# .htaccess blocking one directory correctly, another one incorrectly.

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using this .htaccess in my root to redirect everything to index.php

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !\.(mp3|js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php
```

Then in my directories .htaccess I use this to block direct access

```
RewriteEngine On

deny from all
```

Then to get my html5 audio to play, I put this .htaccess in the audio directory

```
RewriteEngine On

deny from all

allow from index
```

But when I put the same .htaccess file in my javascript directory I don't have access to my js files. Why does it work for the audio directory but not this one?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: How your mp3 files loads to index page? Try to download MP3 file directly from browser.

Comment: @V.Melnychuk - I get a 403 when you try to directly access it, which is what I want. I just don't understand why when I use the same code for the .htaccess in my js directory then none of my js files run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're accessing javascript file from your client computer. MP3 file loads from server side and it allows that approach. That is why you're getting 403 forbidden page. Try to deny it by HTTP_REFERER:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(mp3|js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I guess it may not even make much sense to 403 restrict my JS files anyway, but that's for the solution. :-D Also, what's with the %{REQUEST_FILENAME} and [NC]? Do I need that stuff? Sorry I'm new to .htaccess, if that wasn't totally obvious

Comment: [NC] means that rule is not case sensitive. REQUEST_FILENAME - the full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced. From apache documentation.